# найти близкое к среднему знач. число, нужно исправить код

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int N, i, c, j, sum = 0, array[10000] = { 0 };
    int result;

    scanf("%d", &N);


    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)

        scanf("%d", &array[i]);


    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + array[i];
    }
    sum = sum / N;

    c = sum - array[0];
    result = array[0];

    for (j = 1; j < N; j++)
    {
        if ((sum - array[i]) < c)
        {
            c = sum - array[i];
            result = array[i];
        }
    }

    printf("%d", result);

    return 0;
}
```

нужно задать длину массива, ввести числа и вывести одно наиболее приближенное к среднему значению число (целочисленное), код выше выводит просто первое число которое я ввел(т.е. назначает его наиболее приближенным к среднему значению), а мне нужно чтобы он проверил все числа и вывел наиболее приближенное к среднему значению число.Если не трудно напишите мне исправленный или подскажите что неправильно и как исправить если не трудно))язык си

пример правильно работающего кода:
длина массива=5;
вводим числа
9,
7,
5,
-3,
-1.
среднее знач=5

Comment: В дополнение к ответу @MBo: Вы вычисляете среднее значение как *целое* число. А с чего вы взяли, что оно будет целым? Результат работы программы запросто может получиться неправильным из-за потери точности среднего значения.

Comment: пожалуйста напишите исправленный код если не трудно, а то у меня нули выводит вместо среднего

Comment: я исправил выводит нули

Comment: Последнее исправление неудачное. Цель всё-таки - найти не само среднее, а наиболее близкий к нему элемент.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3 существенных ошибки:

1) Разница со средним может быть как положительной, так и отрицательной, так что искать нужно минимум абсолютного значения

```
c = abs(sum - array[0]);
```

2) Как @AnT подсказал, среднее значение может быть не целым, поэтому следует использовать вещественную переменную.

3) В третьем цикле счётчик j, а индексы i. Чтобы реже допускать такие ошибки, делайте счётчик цикла локальной для блока цикла переменной.

```
int main()
{
      int N, array[10] = { 0 };
int result;
float c, sum = 0.0;

scanf("%d", &N);

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)

    scanf("%d", &array[i]);


for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    sum = sum + array[i];
}
sum = sum / N;

c = fabs(sum - array[0]);
result = array[0];

for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
{
    if (fabs(sum - array[i]) < c)
    {
        c = fabs(sum - array[i]);
        result = array[i];
    }
}

printf("%d", result);
```

Comment: MBo,  можешь назвать инвариант этого кода?

Comment: Тут глупо искать инварианты. Например, в последнем цикле можно придумать такой - на i-м шаге result есть ближайшее к среднему число из просмотренных элементов.